# OpenLayers: how can be ol.FeatureOverlay replaced in 3.13v?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

[Here](https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch06-styling-vector-layers/example-08.html) there is an overlay feature example.

It doesn't work on 3.13 OpenLayers version because of no more supported ol.FeatureOverlay.

How can be it replaced? Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copied & Pasted from [changelog/v3.7.0.md](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/4e7f5582345433923113a7992d00a200208efab4/changelog/v3.7.0.md)

Instead of an `ol.FeatureOverlay`, we now use an `ol.layer.Vector` with an `ol.source.Vector`. If you previously had:

```
var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
  map: map,
  style: overlayStyle
});
featureOverlay.addFeature(feature);
featureOverlay.removeFeature(feature);
var collection = featureOverlay.getFeatures();
```

you will have to change this to:

```
var collection = new ol.Collection();
var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
  map: map,
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: collection,
    useSpatialIndex: false // optional, might improve performance
  }),
  style: overlayStyle,
  updateWhileAnimating: true, // optional, for instant visual feedback
  updateWhileInteracting: true // optional, for instant visual feedback
});
featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(feature);
featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
```

Comment: I used also `featureOverlay.getSource().clear();` instead of `featureOverlay.getFeatures().clear();`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. There is an updated example on OpenLayers website for the latest version ([Vector Layer - v3.14.2](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/vector-layer.html)) where features are highlighted on mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

For OL 6.3.1 [Vector Layer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html) demonstrates the highlighting on mouseover